# how to show and hide imageview inside recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using for loop, and I have around 20 items displaying in recycler view! Now how do I hide/show image view as for loop runs... Here tts is working fine, but when i try to show/hide using this its not happening..

Presently with below code, once for loops ends the entire imageview is affecting, i want it a row wis(show current(image1) & hide previous imageview(image) )

I am calling this method from main Activity class, but the imageview show or hide not happening

activity

```
 ......
 ...... 
private void ConvertTextToSpeech() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   //items.forEach( Multiples obj ->  System.out.println());
    int z=0;
    View holder=null; ImageView imageView=null;ImageView imageView1=null;
    for (Multiples p : items) {

        if(z>0){

            holder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(z).itemView;
            holder.findViewById(R.id.image).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.findViewById(R.id.image1).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        if(z < items.size()) {
              holder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(z).itemView;
              holder.findViewById(R.id.image).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.findViewById(R.id.image1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
        text = p.first + "  " + p.getSecond() + " Za "+p.getResult()+".";
        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
    z++;
    }

}
```

xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
        android:id="@+id/lyt_parent"
        style="@style/RippleStyleBlack"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:focusable="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1px"
                android:background="@color/grey_10" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:textAlignment="gravity" >

                <View
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_large"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image"
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_right" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image1"
                    android:layout_width="51dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_right"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/spacing_middle">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                        android:gravity="center|left"
                        android:text="36"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                        android:textColor="@color/grey_80"
                        android:textSize="30sp"

                        />



                </LinearLayout>





                <View
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_large"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1px"
                android:background="@color/grey_10" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

adapter

```
public class AdapterListAnimation extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Multiples> items = new ArrayList<>();

    private Context ctx;
    private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;
    private int animation_type = 0;
    .........
    .........
```

Comment: if I'm not wrong you asked the same question in the morning

Comment: you need to store the positions you want to *hide*, then call `yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`, then in adapter's `onBindViewHolder` update the visibility according tothe data you stored

Comment: @AshutoshSingh `ha lekin pehele waala thoda alag thha,, yeah comment hatta do aap` i don't think this is English, and the site is English-only

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I could not understand you suggestion, it sounds good. Can you answer me, i am new learner of android.. Logical code will be helpful for me to do

Comment: no. In short - you need to tell adapter that *there is something changed in the data model, and you need to redraw the RecyclerView* once you need to change something there. So when you need to hide something you just store in some list positions of items you need to change, and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. And inside the adapter in the `onBindViewHolder` method, you need to show items corresponding to the data you saved. If it is not clear, then you need a tutorial about how the listView and RecyclerView works, and StackOverflow is not a place to look for tutorials.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko As per your suggestion i have written the code, But still , I do not get the expected output.  .
#1. http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20190403-t2ej-101kb.jpg
#2. I clicked "Button" in debugging mode , and  started debugging http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20190403-otgf-178kb.jpg
#3. adapter class http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20190403-ixzd-212kb.jpg
#4. So, after finishing debugging http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20190403-sgxc-147kb.jpg ... Hope, you understand the situation, Next what to do?

Comment: Everything looks fine except you don't need to call `onBindViewHolder` manually, as it will be called by adapter after you call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Also you don't need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` for every item. Just call it once after the cycle. But for me the problem is not clear now. Everything works as you requested - all images are changed

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Please help, from past 4 days, day & night i am trying to solve this.  I have clearly explained my problem in this new link >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55516858/unable-to-show-imageview-in-recyclerview

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko any help please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to Show imageView in recyclerVIew synchronously with TTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55516858/unable-to-show-imageview-in-recyclerview-synchronously-with-tts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need just add field in your adapter where you will save currently active item. Then call `notifyDataSetChanged`.
Also you should update your `onBindViewHolder` like this:

```
private int currentPosition = -1;

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.textView.setText(items.get(position));
    if (currentPosition == position) {
        holder.img1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.img2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.img1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.img2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}

public void setCurrentPosition(int currentPosition) {
    this.currentPosition = currentPosition;
}
```

I've created a test project to show how it can be implemented. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ku-gbJ-evIc) you can see how it works. [Here](https://github.com/rt1shnik/TextToSpeechExample) is my github repository.

Answer (score 0):

You should not directly change the item view state inside the adapter with the following:

```
holder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(z).itemView;
holder.findViewById(R.id.image).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
holder.findViewById(R.id.image1).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

instead, you need to use a specific method to tell the RecyclerView adapter that you need to change a state of an item view.

Be noted, that RecylerView naturally (in programmatically way) will recyler it's previous item whenever it needs to draw another item. So, you need to keep the state of each item whether using a specific variable inside your model or using a variable to hold each item state.

In case that you don't want to change your model, you can use SparseBooleanArray to hold the state. You can do something like this in your Adapter:

```
public class YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Multiples> mItems;

    // We use this to hold the image state.
    private SparseBooleanArray mImageStates;

    public YourAdapter(List<Multiples> items) {
      this.mItems = items;
      mImageStates = new SparseBooleanArray();

      ...
    }

    @Override
    public YourAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       ...
       return viewHolder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ContactsAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

      int itemPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
      Multiples item = mItems.get(itemPosition);

      // Load the state by the previous saved state
      // default value is false.
      if(mImageStates.get(itemPosition)) {
        // show the images or something.
      } else {
        // hide the images or something.
      }

    }

    public void setState(int position, boolean isVisible) {
      mImageStates.put(position, isVisible);

    }

}
```

now you can change the state item visibility with:

```
yourAdapter.setState(yourItemPosition, true);
```

then notify the adapter about the change with:

```
yourAdapter.notifyItemChanged(yourItemPosition);
```

or reset all if you have change many items with:

```
yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to write a logic on onbindholder then.

```
onBindHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position){
 if(position %2==0)
  imageview.setVisibility(View.Visible);
 else 
  imageview.setVisibility(View.InVisible);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i could not understand your answer! Please help me clearly

Comment: i understand your requirement as display images on even positions so write the logic for that . if that doesn't matches to you leave it.

Comment: @AshutoshSingh take a look at doc about RecyclerView and you will understand. Or just remember. If it have "if", it must need "else".

Comment: yes like that we can apply why your writing adapter codes on Activity class? is their any necessity

Comment: don't write the logic's on activity write all your logic's on adapter level only

Comment: No.  as per docs `Note that unlike ListView, RecyclerView will not call onBindViewHolder method again if the position of the item changes in the data set unless the item itself is invalidated or the new position cannot be determined.`

Comment: Your answer did not work! Still waiting if someone can help me. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

**Finally Got the Solution**

I have added two parameters in your Multiples. In your loop when a condition is true, I am setting variable according to you have done with Image view. after I am notifying `RecyclerView`. so, a callback will come on `onBindViewHolder`. there I have added conditions for show/hide Image view.

suppose left Arrow is `image` & right Arrow is `image1`

**NOTE:** Android Default TextToSpeech does not provide any event listener for complete. So, I have tried a new library that is well maintained and provide [Speech recognition](https://github.com/gotev/android-speech#speech-recognition) and [Text to speech](https://github.com/gotev/android-speech#text-to-speech) functionality.

**Gradle:**

```
implementation 'net.gotev:speech:1.4.0'
```

**Initialization:**

To start using the library, you have to initialize it in your Activity.

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

private count = 0;
private maxCount = 0;

    Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

        Speech.init(this, getPackageName());
        maxCount = items.size();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // prevent memory leaks when activity is destroyed
        Speech.getInstance().shutdown();
    }
}

public class Multiples implements Serializable {

        private Boolean isShowimage = false;
        private Boolean isShowimage1 = false;

        public Boolean getShowimage() {
            return isShowimage;
        }

        public void setShowimage(Boolean showimage) {
            isShowimage = showimage;
        }

        public Boolean getShowimage1() {
            return isShowimage1;
        }

        public void setShowimage1(Boolean showimage1) {
            isShowimage1 = showimage1;
        }
    }

private void ConvertTextToSpeech() {

    if (count < maxCount) {

        reset();
        String text = items.get(count).first + "  " + items.get(count).getSecond() + " Za " + items.get(count).getResult() + ".";

        Speech.getInstance().say(text, new TextToSpeechCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                Log.i("speech", "speech started");
                items.get(count).setShowimage(false);
                items.get(count).setShowimage1(true);

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                Log.i("speech", "speech completed");
                ConvertTextToSpeech();
                count++;
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                Log.i("speech", "speech error");
            }
        });
    }
}

private void reset() {
    for (Multiples p : items) {
        p.setShowimage(true);
        p.setShowimage1(false);
    }
}
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final Multiples item = items.get(position);

        if (item.getShowimage()) {
            holder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        if (item.getShowimage1()) {
            holder.image1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.image1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

    }

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ImageView imageView,imageView1;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            this.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            this.imageView1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        }
    }
```

Comment: On adapter of your code,  "holder.findViewById.."  is INVALID. there is no any method with `findViewById` in holder.   .. Same question i have asked with more explanation here >> : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55516858/unable-to-show-imageview-in-recyclerview  ,please try to help me

Comment: Not working! I have added your code, But its just update the first row see the screenshot of your code output: http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20190406-wszs-117kb.jpg   and as per docs `Note that unlike ListView, RecyclerView will not call onBindViewHolder method again if the position of the item changes in the data set unless the item itself is invalidated or the new position cannot be determined.`

Comment: can you explain what is your logic in ConvertTextToSpeech() function.

Comment: did you mean that you want to know what output i am expecting?

Comment: yes, i can not understand why you have taken two if condition ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191356/discussion-between-monkey-and-vishrut-mavani).

Comment: Your answer did not work! Still waiting if someone can help me. Thanks

Comment: I have updateConvertTextToSpeech() it will automatically move to next item after 1 seconds.

Comment: I have achieved this by using the Library. Please check.